# Валидация сложных правил входных данных

Tags: yii2, валидация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может есть какой-то прием для валидации входных данных, когда правила очень сложны. Я использую YII2 rules() для валидации атрибутов сущности API, но с какого-то момента правил становится столько много, что разобраться и просмотреть их все стаоло очень сложно.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам стоит создать [автономные валидаторы](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/input-validation.md#%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-). (Для проверки на стороне клиента - смотреть [тут](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/input-validation.md#%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-))

Comment: Они помогают, если нужно как-то кастомно валидировать один атрибут, а если атрибуты зависят друг от друга, то начинается ад, чтобы все эти связи разобрать надо просмотреть все правила и прокрутить их в голове

Comment: @OlegKhamov Может стоит разбить вашу форму на несколько простых?